# Embedded Solr on Amazon AWS

Tags: solr, amazon-web-services

Currently, I have developed a web application. In my web application, I used embedded solr server to make indexing. After that I deployed onto the Tomcat 6 on window xp. Everything is ok. Next, I have tried my web application to deploy on Amazon AWS. My platform is linux + mysql. When I deployed, I got the exception related with embedded solr.

```
[ WARN] 19:50:55 SolrCore - [] Solr index directory 'solrhome/./data/index' doesn't     exist. Creating new index...
[ERROR] 19:50:55 CoreContainer - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot   create directory: /usr/share/tomcat6/solrhome/./data/index
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:403)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:552)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:480)
```

So how to fix my problem. I am novie to linux.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the user you are running Solr under does not have permission to access that directory.

Also, which version of Solr are you using? Looks like 3+. The latest version is 4, so it may make sense to try using that from the start. Probably a bit more troubleshooting to start, but a much better pay off that starting with legacy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. That is because of permission affair on Amazon Linux with ec2-user. So , I changed permission by following.

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /usr/share/tomcat6
```

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrOnAmazonEC2**strong text**

t should allow access to ports 22 and 8983 for the IP you're working from, with routing prefix /32 (e.g., 4.2.2.1/32). This will limit access to your current machine. If you want wider access to the instance available to collaborate with others, you can specify that, but make sure you only allow as much access as needed. A Solr instance should not be exposed to general Internet traffic. If you need help figuring out what your IP is, you can always use whatismyip.com. Please note that production security on AWS is a wide ranging topic and is beyond the scope of this tutorial.